# How i can edit the Windows XP setup screen?

Tags: windows-xp, editing, installer, resources

I am making a custom Windows XP installer for education. I need to replace the "Windows Setup" string to another string, like "MediaCenter Setup".

[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: Because it is possible to edit the file resources with Resource Hacker, i just dont know which file to edit to replace this string

Comment: WINNTBBU.DL_ try looking through the .DLL i know this one in particular can change the background. So what you are looking for may be in there. you would just need to extract it with winrar and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

You need to edit the SMSS.exe in system32 folder inside the i386 folder of your setup cd with ResTuner or ResEditor.